# stop auto adjusting scale in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and I want to fix the scale to 0-100 instead of auto scaling.
Here is my JSfiddle and in this scenario I am using two text fields to justify my requirement.
Any help!!

My HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<input id="min" type="text" value="1"></input>
<input id="max" type="text" value="2"></input>
<button id="change">change!</button>
```

Script Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            },
            id: 'my_y',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#F33'
        },
        plotOptions: 
        {
            line: 
            {
                dataLabels: 
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter:function() 
                    {
                        var pcnt = (this.y);
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt,1) + '%';
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            color: '#F33'   
        }]
    });

    // the button handlera
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var yAxis = chart.get('my_y');
    var extremes = yAxis.getExtremes();
    $('#min').attr('value', extremes.min);
    $('#max').attr('value', extremes.max);
    $('#change').click(function() {
        yAxis.setExtremes($('#min').val(),$('#max').val());
        console.info(yAxis)
    });
});
```

And Here is My JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wm7ft/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use min/max or use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions)

Answer (score 2):

You can force the min and max values on the y axis like this:

```
yAxis: {
        min:0,
        max:100
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9q6atpk/